# Yodlee: how to know if a MFA is required before a refresh

Tags: refresh, yodlee

Before fetching the latest transactions, I want to trigger a refresh via https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/startRefresh7 but I can't find any information on the refreshMode.

What is the difference between:

- MFA_REFRESH_MODE
- NORMAL_REFRESH_MODE

I don't want to start the MFA flow if it is not necessary.

Thanks for your help.

PS: I am using fastlink for adding sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFA_REFRESH_MODE is for accounts which require MFA(Multi factor authentication) and NORMAL_REFRESH_MODE for accounts which does not require MFA.

If you are using FastLink for account aggregation then you should be using [startSiteRefresh](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/startSiteRefresh) API. You can pass in the only mandatory fields and then follow the refresh flow from the [flow diagram](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Refresh_Site_Account).

Here you will not have to worry about passing the refresh mode into the API.